# Swift 3 save an image taken from camera and save path on database

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller, phphotolibrary

I can take a picture with phone save it on gallery, but I don't know how can stock the path of picture, so after I can retrieve it from gallery (I don't know yet how retrieve a picture by his path) to show it on my controller.

I have this code which works fine. I can see my image saved on gallery but I don't know how to get his url, witch I want to save on coredata

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    exerciceImage.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    exerciceImage.isHidden = false;

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(exerciceImage.image!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}
func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        // we got back an error!
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    } else {
        let name = image.accessibilityIdentifier;

        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I read that I can use PHPhotoLibrary, but it give me error that it can't cast to nsurl 
Here is what I tried

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    exerciceImage.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    exerciceImage.isHidden = false;

    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        let assetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(atFileURL: info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! URL)
        let assetPlaceholder = assetRequest?.placeholderForCreatedAsset
    }, completionHandler: { success, error in
        // completion handling
        let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! URL;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://medium.com/@Dougly/persisting-image-data-locally-swift-3-8bae72673f8a)
but i edit it because i couldn't load the image after the application was closed, here is my solution hope it will help someone :)

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    exerciceImage.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    exerciceImage.isHidden = false;

    let docDir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let imageUniqueName : Int64 = Int64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000);
    let filePath = docDir.appendingPathComponent("\(imageUniqueName).png");

    do{
        if let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation((info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage)!){
            try pngImageData.write(to : filePath , options : .atomic)
            currentExerciceDto.imageCustom = "\(imageUniqueName).png"
        }
    }catch{
        print("couldn't write image")
    }

}
```

and to **fetch** the image that i just saved, i use this function

```
public static func fetchData(nameImage : String) -> UIImage{

    let docDir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let filePath = docDir.appendingPathComponent(nameImage);

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path){
        if let containOfFilePath = UIImage(contentsOfFile : filePath.path){
            return containOfFilePath;
        }
    }
    return UIImage();

}
```